# Sagemaker -managed containers - script mode

Tags: python, scikit-learn, containers, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

Newbie at Sagemaker. I am trying my hand at the SKLearn managed container and bringing in my own code in script mode. I train my model as follows

```
sklearn=SKLearn(
    entry_point='skl_iris.py',
    framework_version='1.2-1',
    instance_type='ml.m5.large',
    #instance_type='local',
    role=myrole,
    sagemaker_session=mysess,
    hyperparameters={'learning_rate': 0.005}
    )

sklearn.fit(inputs={'train': train_input})
```

I deploy the trained model

```
skl_predictor = sklearn.deploy(
                        initial_instance_count=1, 
                        instance_type='ml.m5.large'
                        )
```

and get the predictions by invoking the automatically created endpoint

```
sgm_runtime = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
inputX=dftest.iloc[0:2,1:]
body=inputX.to_csv(header=False, index=False)
body=json.dumps(body)

response=sgm_runtime.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName=predictor.endpoint_name, 
    ContentType="text/csv",
    Body=body
    )

response=response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
print(response)
```

I have one question and 2 problems:

Question:
Is it possible in script mode and with the SKLearn managed container, to create a model,endpoint config and endpoint instead of having that done automatically with the deploy command?

Problem-1:
The invocation is fine when I ask the endpoint to predict for two or more rows of input data. However, when I try to predict only one row of input I get a CloudWatch error, saying that the input shape is wrong. It is driving me crazy. Mind you, and probably this is important, in my script I only have a model_fn function. I have not yet come around incorporating  input_fn,predict_fn and output_fn functions. Would that be the culprit?

Problem-2:
When I try to train locally, I get the following error message

```
'docker-compose' is not installed. Local Mode features will not work without docker-compose. For more information on how to install 'docker-compose', please, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/
```

I never encountered that in any of the tutorials that I have been through. Is that normal?

I thank you in advance.

PS. In case you need the entire sagemaker ipynb as well as the py script just let me know. I will be grateful for the time you put in.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, yes, you can manually create the model, endpoint config, endpoint in that order instead of `model.deploy()`. The SageMaker SDK is a higher level client that makes it easier to deploy a trained model.
However, you can use the [Boto3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html) to manually create the endpoint. See a sample notebook on creating model, config and endpoint here - https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/boto3/built-in-frameworks/scikit-learn/boto3_scikit_retrain_model_and_deploy_to_existing_endpoint/boto3_scikit_retrain_model_and_deploy_to_existing_endpoint.ipynb

Problem 1: I don't think the input_fn/output_fn should cause any such issue. Wonder if you're sending an index in your input to the endpoint and that's causing a mismatch when you send multiple rows vs a single row?

Problem 2: Where are you running your notebook? Local mode uses Docker to spin up a container to mimic the training job, so if you don't have Docker installed, you'll see this error and won't be able to use local mode. [SageMaker notebook instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi.html) come with Docker pre-installed, so it's a good alternative to running your notebooks if you need to run training in local mode.

Comment: Dear durga_sury. Thank you for 1, and 2. As for Problem 2, I am running on a Sagemaker notebookl, on a ml.t2.medium w/ full IAM permissions. That is what bugs me about getting a message saying that docker-compose is missing.

Comment: That is weird - any chance you can try installing docker on your instance and try?